# How to get started with Jasonette for Android?

Tags: jasonette

I learned today of a new framework called `Jasonette`, but I don't understand how to get started?

When I go to their site https://jasonette.com and click "Try now", the page just redirects to http://web.jasonette.com with this error message:

> There's nothing here, yet

This does not make any sense...

Then I try to go to their documentation site https://github.com/jasonelle/jasonelle/wiki, and I can see lots of examples but nothing helpful on how to actually getting started...

Lower on their web site, I do find a section "**GET AN APP ON YOUR PHONE IN 20 SECONDS**", where it says "**1. Download**" - but there is no link (so download from where exactly, hmm...) ??

Hence, my question is actually quite simple: How to get started for Android - where to download (cannot find link anywhere) ?

I also tried to search for `Jasonette` on the Google Play store but could not find anything there either.

I'm using the latest Android version on my phone (Nokia).

Please help - thank you in advance :-)

Comment: isn't this the github location you are looking for - https://github.com/Jasonette/JASONETTE-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found the page for exact steps on how to getting started for Android here (this was what I was looking for but not very easy to find):

https://jasonelle-archive.github.io/docs/legacy/android/

It seems, you need to also download and use `Android Studio` and then connect the phone in order to deploy the app to the phone and thus not deployed by installing an app from the play store, which I thought ... this was not described very clearly on the other sites.

I did also managed to find a link to a place, where you can download an actual .APK file here (click the arrow to open a little Asset menu, if this is not visible):

https://github.com/jasonelle/jasonelle/releases